# Открыть ballon по клику на внешней ссылке

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-maps-embed, yandex-places-api, yandex-static-maps-api

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

//Клик по div после которого должен открыться балун и отцентрироваться позиция
$('.contacts-map-link').click(function()
{
  var geo_adres = $(this).attr('attr-geo');
  var myMap = init(geo_adres, 1);
  FirstMetka(geo_adres, myMap);
});

function init(geo_adres, my_map = false)
  {
   myMap = new ymaps.Map('map_append_yandex', 
   {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 16
   });
   
   myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(); 
   
   if(my_map)
   {
    return myMap;
   }
   else
   {
    ymaps.geocode(geo_adres, 
    {
     results: 1
    }).
    then(function (res, geo_code) 
    {
     var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
     coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
     bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
     firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
     firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
     myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
     myMap.setBounds(bounds, 
     {
      checkZoomRange: true
     });
    });
   }
  }

function FirstMetka(geo_adres, myMap)
{
    myMap.firstGeoObject.balloon.open();
}
</script>
```

```html
<div attr-geo="г. Тула, ул. Сойфера, д. 6" class="contacts-map-link"  rel="nofollow"> Перейти на сойфера </div>
```

Возвращенный "myMap" почему-то не является экземпляром пространства ymaps.Map.
Подскажите как решить проблему. В перспективе у меня будет ObjectCollection() Т.е несколько гео-объектов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/nqsxbf1o/ - рабочий пример

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    //Клик по div после которого должен открыться балун и отцентрироваться позиция
    $('.contacts-map-link').click(function() {
    var geo_adres = $(this).attr('attr-geo');
      var myMap = createMap();
    getGeocodeReq(myMap, geo_adres).then(function () {
        createFirstMetka(myMap, geo_adres);
    });
    });
});

function getGeocodeReq(myMap, geo_adres) {
    return ymaps.geocode(geo_adres, {
                results: 1
    }).then(function (res, geo_code) {
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
        coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
        bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');                                          
    firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
        firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
        myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
        myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
    });
}

function createMap() {
        return new ymaps.Map('map_append_yandex', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
      zoom: 16
    });
}

function createFirstMetka(myMap, geo_adres)
{   
    myMap.geoObjects.get(0).balloon.open();
}
```

Не совсем понял, что и в какой последовательности должно происходить.
Если имелось ввиду другое, пишите.

Comment: Не совсем так. Сейчас посмотрю Ваш вариант повнимательнее.
1) Инициализируем карту:
function auto_click()
{
 $("#tula" ).trigger("click");
 CreateMap('г. Тула, ул. Сойфера, д. 6');
}
setTimeout(auto_click, 1000);
2) Без пересоздание карты кликом по внешней ссылке открываем балун гео метки.

Моя проблема в том, что как только карта уже была создана, я не могу из моей функции Init вернуть объект: "firstGeoObject", чтобы изменить событие Open для Ballon.

Comment: Живой пример из шаблона не сочтите за рекламу пожалуйста:
https://arealtypro.citrus-demo.ru/kontakty/
P.S разобраться полностью как это работает по ссылке выше не смог.

Comment: При нажатии на ссылку должна создаваться карта или уже на созданной создаваться метка, по данным из геокодера, а в ней открываться балун?

Comment: На уже созданной карте, на которой уже есть гео метки после клика фактически просто переместить центр и открыть балун.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqsxbf1o/1/

Comment: Да, это абсолютно подходящий вариант! Thx's!